# Scraping multiple pages using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape this website: https://www.cartrade.com/buy-used-cars/p-10

My code:

```
import scrapy

class ShopcluesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'example'
   allowed_domains = ['www.cartrade.com/buy-used-cars']
   start_urls = ['https://www.cartrade.com/buy-used-cars/']
   custom_settings = { 'FEED_URI' : 'tmp/data.csv'}

   def parse(self, response):
       # Extract product information
       titles = response.xpath('//div[@class = "carimgblk"]/a/img/@title').extract()
       URLs = response.xpath('//div[@class = "carimgblk"]/a/meta/@content').extract()
       prices = response.xpath('//div[@class = "cr_prc"]/text()').extract()

       for item in zip(titles,prices,URLs):
           scraped_info = {
               'title' : item[0].strip(),
               'price' : item[1].strip().replace(',', ''),
               'URL': item[2].strip(),
           }    
           yield scraped_info

       next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
       if next_page:
          yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page),callback=self.parse)
```

The issue is that it's not scraping all pages. I also noticed prices are not totally correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your pagination seems to be working fine on my end; Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding parsing accuracy: the general way of parsing products out of html is finding product blocks and iterating through them and parsing every block individiaully.

In your example you can see that every car listing has it's own `<div>` block with class `carlistblk`:

```
cars = response.css('.carlistblk')
for car in cars:
    item = {}
    item['title'] = car.xpath('.//img/@title')
    ...
    yield item
```

Your zip method can be easily disrupted if one listing doesn't have a single field, then you have 10 titles and 9 prices - the data will be zipped inaccurately.